# Is there a formal common Internet threat model?

Tags: attacks, internet, threat-modeling

I'm looking for a common Internet threat model that describes active attacks formally. By active attacks I mean attacks of an attacker with literally unlimited resources and full control over the network, i.e. the attacker can intercept, modify and suppress every communication in the network but has no access to any of the communicating hosts. The ACTIVE ATTACK scenario of RFC 3552 seems to describe this model in an informal way.

Comment: By formal, do you mean "math"?

Comment: I mean math or very precise natural language.

Comment: There's also 7624, but I suspect that's not what you want.  I think you need to clarify your question.  What do these rfcs not achieve?

Answer (score 2):

#### *Formal model* for an *active attack*

Sadly there is no way to give you a correct and unique answer.

Please read the [RFC3552](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3552) you pointed out carefully:

> #### 3.3.5. Man-In-The-Middle
>
> A MAN-IN-THE-MIDDLE attack combines the above techniques...

About which type of *active* or *passive* attacks that have to be considered:

Both techniques will probably be used (mostly by complement, one with the other) to try and get the data the attacker is after.

Depending on *what* you have to protect and *who* could be interested in parts of your data the threat model could be constantly changing even for the same attacker on your system.

Sadly this means that there really is no available *attack cookbook* and this is not because they are keeping this secret, but because each target *and* attack are different and each way the attack happens(exploit, security hole, phishing site...) are constantly different, changing, and evolving.

But from my point of view, the **most** vulnerable element of any securisation edifice stay human: first the **user**, but the **programmer** too!.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but it sounds like you want

1. A common threat modeling system that
2. allows you to make distinctions between type of attacks

Are you familiar with the STIX taxonomy? You may be able to represent your "full control attacker" by creating a set of extensible Indicators and Observables and aligning it with TTPS.

http://stixproject.github.io/data-model/1.2/indicator/IndicatorType/

Or is it more that you are looking for a common term for the idea of "attacks of an attacker with literally unlimited resources and full control over the network, i.e. the attacker can intercept, modify and suppress every communication in the network but has no access to any of the communicating hosts"?